# What is the diff. between resttemplate request and web browser request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, http-proxy

I have a spring boot app that deployed on remote server and i use this app to upload files. It works perfectly when i request over a web browser form. But, when i use resttemplate, although i set timeout, my resttemplate client code gets **java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect**. And i tested my restemplate code on my localhost succesfully, it works.

My questions are that:

1. What does web browser do differently?
2. Is it related to proxy issues? (Remote server doesn't have a proxy)

Kind regards.

Comment: Looks like a Proxy error

Comment: are you using the same address in the resttemplate which you use on the web browser?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jens, actually i am a bit confused. Becouse remote server doesn't have a proxy. In this case, i don't know what should be set in my resttemplate code.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Thomson Ignesious.  I am using same adrress

Comment: @Coşkun Your local Computer is behind a Proxy?

Comment: Sorry for my late response @Jens. No it is not